# Create GameObject and save in Hierarchy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to create gameObjects (text, 3d stuff, etc.) from scripts and save them in the scene.
For example: If I use a script like this,

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Start()
    {
        GameObject plane = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Plane);
    }
}
```

the "plane" will be add in Hierarchy temporarily (just after you press start).

I'm looking for some way to create a lot of gameObjects automatically (through a script, api, etc.) and save them in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are talking of persistent GameObject after stopping scene i suppose.

The only possibility to make gameObject instance pop inside your scene hierarchy and stay after scene played and stopped is to use `CustomEditors`.

You have to know, unity editor is based on Unity Gui, so you can easily add buttons make it run some specific script coded by you, inside windows menu (for example).

But you can also custom the mouse right click on scene hierarchy to allow peoples to create instances of a allowed gameObject and add this created instance directly on child of previously clicked gameobject from the scene etc...

Or make create your own tools script, and add it as component on Gameobject and with specific layout for it and rendered by Unity Editor.

For use customEditor step by step :

1 - Create a folder named `Editor` inside `Assets/` root project hierarchy

2 - Create a script like bellow, which is using reference to `UnityEditor` and add you could use the commented Attribute. At the end you have to make your class extend From Editor class.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
// uncomment this line bellow if you want to create customEditor script which you will be able to use on gameObject as component.
// typeof give script type , it's a script created as component and extending from Monobehaviour, he contain value etc.. he could be manipulated from this CustomEditor script via button who call Methodes.
//[CustomEditor(typeof(YourScriptComponent))]

public class MyNewCustomEditor : Editor
{}
```

for more examples of customEditors script look at unity doc: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Editor.html

3 - Create methodes to be used and called out of scene Playing mode.
you have to create buttons inside `OnInspectorGUI()` function which will call your methodes for instantiate inside scenes some GameObjects.

4 - WARNING , To instantiate resources like prefabs etc, you have to put yours needed resources inside folder called `Resources` and use inside your script the  `Resources.Load()` methode.

see the doc for more information , it's pretty simple to use : http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html

Hope it will help, see You.

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar question asked [over here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/11858/programatically-instantiating-gameobjects-to-the-e.html).

You want be making an Editor Script then using pretty much the same logic you would use at runtime. Here is the [Unity Docs on editor scripts](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Editor.html).

You can just make a C# script and put it in the "Editor" folder. If you want it to appear in the editor as a dropdown option you can throw in "[MenuItem("MyTools/CreateGameObjects")]" before a function as shown in the other Stack Overflow answer.